# How to scroll ListView to a particular position and change the text color

Tags: android, android-widget

There is custom view and a ListView, both are coupled as  such if one changes its state other must change. I am able to control custom view if one item of ListView is selected.

If a item is selected in custom view, corresponding item in List view should become visible and text in it must be hilighted.

I tried

listView.smoothScrollToPosition(clueIndex);

no scrolling happens on execution of this line.

Second question -

How can I get access to TextView in a particular adaptor postion and change its text color   outside OnItemLongClickListener() ?

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved, due to error clueIndex was always -1.